# How to change the link urls in laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to change the link urls in my laravel project from:

```
www.mywebsite.com/products/1/1
```

to

```
www.mywebsite.com/products/NameOfcategoryOfProduct/NameOfProduct
```

Here is my routes/web.php content:

```
Route::get("products", 'ProductController@index')->name('products.index');
Route::get("products/{groupement}/{group}", 'ProductController@category')->name('products.categories');
Route::get("products/{groupement}/{group}/{category}", 'ProductController@product')->name('products.list');
Route::get("products/{groupement}/{group}/{category}/{product}", 'ProductController@detail')->name('product.detail');
```

Here is my products index page:

```
@section('products-list')

    <div class="list-groupement row row-cols-xl-2 row-cols-1 justify-content-center">
        @foreach ($groupements as $groupement)
            <div class="col">
                <div class="groupement-item" style="border-color: #{{$groupement->color_groupement}}">
                    <div class="detail-g d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                        <div>
                            <h3 style="color: #{{$groupement->color_groupement}}">{{$groupement->name_groupement}}</h3>
                            <span>{{$groupement->description}}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div style="width: 250px">
                            <img src="{{asset('img/group/'.$groupement->img_groupement.'')}}" alt="{{$groupement->name_groupement}}" style="width: 250px">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="list-one-group">
                        <div class="title-list-product row row-cols-xl-3 row-cols-md-3 row-cols-sm-3 row-cols-2 justify-content-center">
                            @foreach ($groups as $group)
                                @if ($group->id_groupement == $groupement->id)
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="title-product {{ (request()->is('products/'.$groupement->id.'/'.$group->id.'') || request()->is('products/'.$groupement->id.'/'.$group->id.'/*')) ? 'active-product' : '' }}">
                                        <a href="{{route('products.categories', ["groupement"=>$groupement->id, 'group' => $group->id])}}">{{$group->name_group}}</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                @endif
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>

    
                
@endsection
```

Can you help me with that? let me know if I need to add more explanations or source code to other ressources.

Comment: You have not mentioned what the problem you're facing is. From a quick look, your code looks logical, so we're unable to help without you telling us what the problem is exactly.

Comment: I want to change the link url for the products page from www.mysite.com/1/1 to www.mysite.com/nameofcategory/nameofproduct

Comment: Pardon me, your description was clear, I just wasn't focused.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is use the name of the columns that you want to show there. Let's say you have `$product->category` and `$product->name`. That means your route will be:

```
Route::get("products/{category}/{name}", 'ProductController@detail')->name('product.detail');
```

And your controller will look like this:

```
public function detail($category, $name){
```

And of course, when you call the route, you must use the category and the name instead of the `id` now.

Answer (score 0):

In route bindings, pass NameOfcategoryOfProduct and NameOfProduct instead of IDs.

In the controller instead of doing a Find and looking for the IDS use a where and look for NameOfcategoryOfProduct and NameOfProduct

Like this

```
<a href="{{route('products.categories', ["groupement"=>$groupement->NameOfProduct, 'group' => $group->name_group])}}">{{$group->name_group}}</a>
```

Dont forget make changes in your controller